# Javascript replace not working as expected

Tags: javascript, replace

This is my code

```
var tmp = document.body.outerHTML.match(/<b>Location: <\/b>([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,])([^\s]+) <br>/i);
DataExtractor.AddHeader(14, 'id_country');
  var country
    if( tmp ){country = tmp[1]
   }
  else{alert('country is not set')} 
DataExtractor.AddResult(14, country);`
```

This returns the value of 'UK' or 'USA' or whatever is the country code is, but I need to replace this value to correspond  with a country ID stored elsewhere so they can be compared.  I therefore need to be able to tell this piece of code to replace the value UK with 75. I have tried the following, but it just didn't work.

```
var tmp = document.body.outerHTML.match(/<b>Location: <\/b>([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,])([^\s]+) <br>/i);
DataExtractor.AddHeader(14, 'id_country');
  var country
    if( tmp ){country = tmp[1]
    if (country){
      for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
      country[i] = country[i].replace("UK","75")
}
    else{alert('country is not set')}
DataExtractor.AddResult(14, country[i]);
}}
```

Does anyone see where it's gone wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted here is not syntactically valid -- where should the closing quote and parenthesis go in that final `alert`? Additionally, it would be helpful if you could indent your code blocks so it's easier for people to understand your problem and answer your question.

Comment: Sorry have amended the errors as mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

country contains a string - eg "UK" and you are then taking each character of it "U" or "K" and trying to replace "UK" with "75" which never matches.

```
if (country){
    country = country.replace("UK","75")
}
```

This should work